# What is "#" in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am looking at a `.cshtml` file and I see a syntax like this:

```
<span>
 #if(data.PersonImage){# <img src  
</span>
```

I know `@` is for writing `C#` code, I also looked at this guide below but still couldn't find what is `#` doing?

https://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/

Comment: That's not Razor, as far as I can tell, it looks like some javascript framework

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I know they are using type script and Kendo UI too

Comment: not using in razor, never using # do nothing maybe comment, but using type script

Comment: “they are using type script and Kendo UI too” is pretty important information to leave out of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to know: does it start with `@`?

- Yes (and isn't followed by another `@`, i.e `@@`) => Razor
- No => something else

What you are seeing is the [Kendo UI template syntax](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview). Similar to razor, the documentation reads:

> The # (hash) sign is used to mark areas in a template that should be
>   replaced by data when the template is executed